# How to tell if a given equation is not a class equation of a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Which of the following cannot  be  a  class  equation  of  a  group  of  order $10$?

1. $1+1+1+2+5=10$
2. $1+2+3+4  =10$
3. $1+2+2+5  =10$
4. $1+1+2+2+2+2=10$

As I  can  see options 2, 1  and  4  are  not   class  equations as $3$  does  not  divide  $10$  and  for 4, $|Z(G)|=2$  will  make  the  group  abelian and  the  equation  absurd. So the only possibility is option 3. But Iam  not  sure  whether there could be other arguments besides the ones I  have used to dismiss 1, 2, 4 that could dismiss also 3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible Class equation for a group](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549593/possible-class-equation-for-a-group)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's only one nonabelian group of order $10$:
\begin{align*}
D_5 = \langle a, x:\, a^5 = 1, x^2 = 1, xa = a^{-1}x\rangle.
\end{align*}
A brief computation shows that the conjugacy classes of $D_5$ are
\begin{gather*}
\{1\} \\
\{a, a^4\} \\
\{a^2, a^3\} \\
\{x, ax, a^2x, a^3x, a^4x\},
\end{gather*}
which matches item (3) in the problem.

Comment: No thanks necessary, but you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

for option (1): sum of the 1's is 3 but not divide the 10 so option (1) is not correct.

for option (2): 3 is not factor of 10 so option (2) also not correct.

for option (4): sum of the 1's is 2 and |G/Z(G)|=5, this means center of G is the whole group, this is a contradiction so option (4) also not correct.

So (3) is the only possible class equation of order 10, so options (1), (2) and (4) are the right choices.

Comment: However you show no reason for why (3) *is* a class equation of  group of order 10.