# Any group of order $n$ satisfying $\gcd (n, \varphi(n)) =1$ is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, totient-function

Sorry for the last mistaken problem I just posted. Now I know that only having the order being odd square free is not enough for a group to be cyclic.

Here's the complete problem which the main goal is to show that any group of order $n$ satisfies $\gcd (n,\varphi(n))=1$ is cyclic. It asks me to do it in the following way:

(a) If $n > 2$, $n$ is an odd squarefree integer.

(b) Show that there is a $H = G/N$ of prime order.

(c) Show that $G \cong N \times H$ and $G$ is abelian.

(d) $G$ is cyclic.

---

Any ideas is appreciated.

Comment: $\phi(2)=1\ldots$

Comment: @Tim.Ratigan Nice point, I was so careless...

Comment: @Tim.Ratigan Now it is corrected. Thank you~

Comment: I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proofs of a), b), d) seem correct. To prove c) notice first that if you take an element $x\in G$ such that order of $x$ equals $p_{i_n}$, you have $\{e/N,x/N,\ldots,x^{p_{i_n}-1}/N\}=G/N$, so the exact sequence $0\to N\to G\to H\to 0$ splits and $G\cong N\rtimes H$.

Therefore, it's enough to show that $H$ can't act nontrivially on $N$. But by induction (with respect to number of prime factors of $G$) you can assume that $N\cong {\bf Z}_{\lvert N\rvert}$ which has automorphism group isomorphic to ${\bf Z}_{\lvert N\rvert}^*$.

From that, an action of $H$ on $N$ induces a homomorphism from $H$ to ${\bf Z}_{\lvert N\rvert}^*$. But orders of $H$ and ${\bf Z}_{\lvert N\rvert}^*$ are coprime by assumption, so the only action is the trivial one and we're done.

Note that the converse of the theorem you are to prove is also true: if $n, \varphi(n)$ are *not* coprime, then there's a group of order $n$ which is not cyclic: if $n$ is not squarefree, then this is trivial (${\bf Z}_{n/p}\times {\bf Z}_{p}$ has order $n$ and is non-cyclic). Otherwise, if you take $p$ such that $p$ divides both $n$ and $\varphi(n)$, then $p$ divides $\varphi(n/p)$ and you have a nontrivial semidirect product ${\bf Z}_{n/p}\rtimes {\bf Z}_p$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'm just a starter on algebra so I don't really understand some of your terms... But as far as I can see is that $G \cong N \rtimes H$ since we can find a subgroup $K$ of $G$ of order $p_{i_n}$ and get $G = NK$. And then we only need to show that $K$ is normal in $G$ in order to turn the semidirect product into direct product (right?) So how do we show that $K$ is normal?

Comment: @user112564: the semidirect $N\rtimes H$ product is a direct product if and only if the action of $H$ on $N$ is trivial. But I've shown that the action must be trivial. What's confusing about this part?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't understand the term "action of $H$ on $N$ is trivial", moreover, what does it mean to say "$H$ acts on $N$"?

Comment: @user112564: see the section of Wikipedia article on semidirect product: [semidirect products and group homomorphisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product#Semidirect_products_and_group_homomorphisms) and the article on [group action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action). Those should contain all the information needed to bring you up to speed with the terms I used. A trivial action is an action such that $h\cdot n= n$ for each $h,n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I'm totally clear.

Comment: @user112564: You're welcome. :)

Comment: @tomasz I'm not entirely sure why $H$ and ${\bf Z}_{\lvert N\rvert}^*$ being coprime imply the action can only be trivial. Could you give a hint, or it something that follows right from the definition?

Comment: @ToNoAvail27 Because any homomorphism between two groups of coprime order has to be trivial. Hope that help :)

Comment: @ToNoAvail27: Take a homomorphism $\phi\colon H\to {\bf Z}_{\lvert N\rvert}^*$. What could the order of $\phi[H]$ be?

Comment: @tomasz I see it now. $|\phi[H]|$ must divide the order of $G$ by the 1st isomorphism theorem, but $|\phi[H]|$ also divides the order of ${\bf Z}_{\lvert N\rvert}^*$, and since the orders are relatively prime, $|\phi[H]|$ must be $1$, thus $\phi$ is the trivial homomorphism. Thanks!