# Number of normal subgroups of a non abelian group of order $21$... CSIR December $2013$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Question is to :

Find the number of Normal subgroups of a nonabelian group $G$ of order $21$ other than $\{e\}$ and $G$.

What I have done so far is :

As $|G|=21=3\cdot7$  we have :

No. of sylow $3$ subgroups $1+3k$ dividing $7$ leaving out possibilities $1$ or $7$

No. of sylow $7$ subgroups $1+7k$ dividing $3$ leaving out only possibilities $1$.

So, we have a unique sylow $7$ subgroup and so it is normal.

I remember somehow that any normal group should come from a normal sylow subgroup or something like that.

S0, I prefer to conclude there is only one Normal subgroup for a non abelian group of order $21$.

Please let me know if this is true and please help me to fill that gap :

> I remember somehow that any normal group should come from a normal sylow subgroup or something like that.

Thank you.

Comment: I hope this post is usefull for you http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117500/conjugacy-classes-of-the-nonabelian-group-of-order-21

Comment: The answer is correct, since if the $3$ -Sylow subgroup is normal, you can show that $G$ is cyclic (and therefore abelian).

Comment: @chuyenvien94 : Thank you for the link :)

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: @Ludolila : Yes Yes... I am sure the sylow 3 subgroup is not normal.... My concern is how do i make sure there is no other Normal subgroup...

Comment: @srijan : What would be the problem if the title is with "CSIR 2013"??

Comment: The order of a non-trivial subgroup is either $3$ or $7$. Any group of order $3$ (in this case) is a $3$-Sylow subgroup... (Same goes for order $7$). So what other options you have?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Who knows about csir except Indians. Otherwise you may re change your title but I feel it looks odd.

Comment: @Praphulla Koushik: You can check this link for more informations http://www.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/oldcourses/236Hs08/exam2soln.pdf

Comment: @Ludolila : Oh yes... I got it... This is a very valid point... Thank you.. :)

Comment: @srijan That is just for my reference though it look odd....

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik cool :)

Comment: @srijan : yes yes.. No hard feelings... :)

Comment: A general result can be found in here http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/05/13/classify-nonabelian-groups-of-order-pq-p-and-q-distinct-primes/

Comment: why negative vote?

Comment: @chuyenvien94 Thank you :)

Comment: @Praphulla Koushik: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To sum up the comments:

There is a normal subgroup of order $7$ (the $7$-Sylow subgroup). 
The $3$-Sylow subgroup is not normal, since otherwise $G$ would be cyclic (and therefore abelian).

Any non trivial (normal) subgroup is of order $3$ or $7$, and thus has to be a Sylow subgroup (in this particular case).

To conclude: $G$ has only one non-trivial normal subgroup.

Comment: Sorry that i have taken back my "Accept"... My Actual intention was to study my vague idea "I remember somehow that any normal group should come from a normal sylow subgroup or something like that"... Please help me to see this

Comment: Well there is a connection between Sylow subgroups of a group and its normal subgroups, but it doesn't apply here (I think...). The connection is as follows: let $G$ be a group and $P$ is one of its Sylow-subgroups. Then if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, the intersection $N \cap P$ is a Sylow-subgroup of $N$.

Comment: @ludolia : Yes Yes... This makes perfect sense.. Thank you :)